# Get Immediate Successor in a Given Number Sequence

Tags: java, algorithm, math, numbers

In an infinite sequence of numbers `[2, 5, 7, 22, 25, 27, 52, 55, 57, 72, 75, 77, 222, ...]`.
Given any number in this sequence get the immediate successor number.

```
Example:
Input   Output
22      25
77      222
5       7
```

I have written the below logic to find the next number in a sequence.

```
public static int getNextNumInSequence(Integer sequenceCurrentNum) {
    List<Integer> sequence = new ArrayList<>();
    sequence.add(2);
    sequence.add(5);
    sequence.add(7);
    
    if(sequence.get(0).equals(sequenceCurrentNum))
        return sequence.get(1);
    else if(sequence.get(1).equals(sequenceCurrentNum))
        return sequence.get(2);
    
    //This is not a finite loop, just for my testing i am running 300 iterations.       
    for(int i=0;i<300;i++) {                    
        if(sequence.get(i).equals(sequenceCurrentNum)) {
            return sequence.get(i+1);
        }
        
        int nextVal = sequence.get(i)*10;
        
        Integer firstSeq = nextVal + sequence.get(0);
        Integer secondSeq = nextVal + sequence.get(1);
        Integer thirdSeq = nextVal + sequence.get(2);
        
        sequence.add(firstSeq);
        sequence.add(secondSeq);
        sequence.add(thirdSeq);     
        
        if(firstSeq.equals(sequenceCurrentNum)) {
            return secondSeq;               
        }else if(secondSeq.equals(sequenceCurrentNum)) {
            return thirdSeq;                
        }
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

> My Approach:
>
> 1. I am constructing the entire sequence from the beginning
> 2. Then checking if we have reached to the given number in sequence.
> 3. Then return the successor.
>
> Drawbacks:
>
> 1. I am constructing the entire sequence to reach to given number.
> 2. Memory wise and performance wise not suggestable.

Please help to understand, is there any better approach to get the successor without constructing entire sequence.

> Example: Given 277755 should return 277757. (Without constructing the
> entire sequnce)

Note: The sequence will not be provided as an input to our function. The only input we will be given is a valid number from the sequence.

Comment: Without knowing what structure the succession follows no, is not possible and you must read numbers until the given one.

Comment: @josejuan You need to read the code to understand how the sequence is built.

Comment: ok is not _"in a"_ is _"in this"_ sequence. Thks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
public static int getNextNumInSequence(Integer sequenceCurrentNum) {
    int head = sequenceCurrentNum / 10;
    int tail = sequenceCurrentNum % 10;
    int headNext = head == 0 ? 2 : getNextNumInSequence(head);
    if (headNext == 0) return 0;
    switch (tail) {
    case 2: return head * 10 + 5;
    case 5: return head * 10 + 7;
    case 7: return headNext * 10 + 2;
    default: return 0;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0, k = 2; i < 20; ++i, k = getNextNumInSequence(k))
        System.out.println(i + " : " + k);
}
```

output:

```
0 : 2
1 : 5
2 : 7
3 : 22
4 : 25
5 : 27
6 : 52
7 : 55
8 : 57
9 : 72
10 : 75
11 : 77
12 : 222
13 : 225
14 : 227
15 : 252
16 : 255
17 : 257
18 : 272
19 : 275
```

You can also get n-th number.

```
public static int getNumAtIndex(int n) {
    int h = n / 3;
    int t = n % 3;
    return (h == 0 ? 0 : getNumAtIndex(h) * 10)
        + (t == 0 ? 2 : t == 1 ? 5 : 7);
}
```

test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        System.out.println(i + " : " + getNumAtIndex(i));
}
```

output:

```
0 : 2
1 : 5
2 : 7
3 : 52
4 : 55
5 : 57
6 : 72
7 : 75
8 : 77
9 : 522
```

Comment: `getNumAtIndex(h-1)`

Answer (score 1):

First try to understand what is the logic behind the sequence. If you look carefully to the numbers, you may see counting in ternary base. To be more clear, let's replace '2' by '0', '5' by '1' and '7' by '2'. Then your sequence becomes:

```
(0, 1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 100, 101, 102, ...)
```

It's just counting.
So the thing is to get the next number in ternary base, but using the digits 2, 5, 7. We must take care of digit 7: if we increment it, we get 2 but we have a carry for the digit before.

Here is a sample code:

```
public static Integer getNextNumInSequence(Integer number)
{
    int digits[] = {2,5,7};
    int idx_digits[] = {-1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 1, -1, 2, -1, -1};
    Integer next_number = 0;
    int carry = 1;
    Integer pow10 = 1;
    while (number>0)
    {
        int digit = number%10;      //extract last digit
        int idx_d = idx_digits[digit];      //get index of digit -- must be 0,1 or 2
        if (idx_d==-1)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid number");
            return -1;
        }
        next_number += digits[(idx_d+carry)%3]*pow10;   //compute next digit in sequence, taking care of the carry
        carry = (digit==7)?1:0;     //carry is 1 only if the current digit is 7
        pow10 *= 10;            //increment 
        number /= 10;           //erase last digit
        if (carry==0)           //if no carry, we can stop the loop here, it's not useful to continue
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    // at this point, either number>0 or carry==1
    return ((carry>0)?2:number)*pow10+next_number;      //final number is the digit sequence [2 if carry else number ; next_number]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this recursively.

If the final digit of the given number is 2 or 5, then it is easy: just change that final digit to 5 or 7 respectively.

Otherwise (when the final digit is 7), solve the problem without the last digit, and then append the digit 2 to that result. Of course, "without last digit" means an integer division by 10, and "appending" means multiplying by 10 and then adding the value of the digit.

Here is the function:

```
public static int getNextNumInSequence(Integer curr) {
    if (curr % 10 == 2) return curr + 3;
    if (curr % 10 == 5) return curr + 2;
    if (curr == 7) return 22;
    return getNextNumInSequence(curr / 10) * 10 + 2;
}
```

Note that one call has worst case time complexity of O(logn) where n is the value of the function argument, but **amortised** time complexity is O(1) per call.

Answer (score 0):

To construct the list, you can simply do this:

```
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(2, 5, 7, 22, 25, 27, 52, 55, 57, 72, 75, 77, 222);
```

Note that there are cases where there is not successor. Here I will return null in those cases:

```
public static Integer getNextNumInSequence(List<Integer> list, Integer num) {
    int pos = list.indexOf(num);
    if (pos >= 0 && pos+1 < list.size()) {
        return list.get(pos+1);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note that I've added a parameter `list` so that you don't have to build the list each time you want to do a search.

In your example, the list is sorted; If it's always the case, you can use a binary search: `Collections.binarySearch(list, num)` instead of `list.indexOf(num)`.

Comment: He is asking for _"is there any better approach to get the successor without constructing entire sequence"_ (obviously `Arrays.asList` construct the entire sequence).

Comment: The entire sequence is infinite.

Comment: @josejuan I've answered that question.

Comment: @Olivier `for(int i=0;i<300;i++)` is finite

Comment: @MauricePerry nope, you point a (binary) search he ask to _"not constructing"_

Comment: Well, you're right, the OP should clarify where that `300` comes from.

Comment: @Olivier if the sequence is infinite, you can't store it. You need an algorithm to build it.

Comment: @josejuan I have moved the code building the list out of the search method. That's how I've understood the question (but it's not very clear)

Comment: @Uppicharla OK. I've created a new answer

Answer (score 0):

OK. If I understand correctly, you have three initial values:

```
static final int[] initial = {2, 5, 7};
```

and you can calculate the value at position `ix` like this:

```
private static int calculate(int ix) {
    int div = ix/initial.length;
    int rest = ix%initial.length;
    int value = 0;
    if (div > 0) {
        value = 10*calculate(div-1);
    }
    return value+initial[rest];
}
```

To get the successor of `num`:

```
public static Integer getNextNumInSequence(int num) {
    for (int i = 0; ; ++i) {
        int cur = calculate(i);
        if (cur == num) {
            return calculate(i+1);
        } else if (cur > num) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```